# Application works perfect in debug mode but unexpected error when executed after publish

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, gridview, combobox

I've made a VB application for school. I've put a lot of time in it and I was so happy when I finally finished it. It works perfect in debug mode.

Now the problem is: when I publish it, install it and execute it, I get errors when I open certain forms.
What I noticed is that only the forms which have "****.Datasource = " in their code produce these errors. (for example: `cbVertrekpunt.DataSource = getListofBstations()`)

Original function for GridView DataSource:

```
Public Function getStation(ByVal station As String) As Station

        Return (From s In treinDataContext.Stations Select s Where s.naam = station).First

    End Function
```

Here's an error of one of the forms: first line in english: Sequence contains no elements

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Reeks bevat geen elementen
   bij System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult)
   bij System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries)
   bij System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)
   bij System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
   bij System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   bij TreinplannerBL.TreinController.getStation(String station)
   bij TreinplannerBL.RittenbeheerderController.getEindstationMogelijkMetBeginstation(String beginstation)
   bij RitController.AankoopTicket.cbVertrekpunt_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.set_SelectedIndex(Int32 value)
   bij RitController.AankoopTicket.AankoopTicket_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   bij System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Extra information: I'm sure the problem lies within the fact that functions are datasources cause when I open forms in which no functions are datasources, I get no error. When I open forms which have ".DataSource = " I get errors, but when I delete these lines, the errors don't appear anymore

Comment: yes I did, but when I publish my VB application I get an unexpected error. And when I delete the functions as datasources I don't have any errors. :/ Maybe I have to dim my function into some list or table or something and give that list or table as datasource. I'm really hopeless cuz when I run debug, my app works flawless without any errors. But when I publish it, execute it and open a form which has a function as datasource in the code, it gives an error.

Comment: That was sort of the point: your comment needs to be a part of the question-- you didn't give any hints what problems you were having with the code.

Comment: the error contains a lot of the 'SQL' word. :(

Comment: Edit your question and post that error information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You just need to load the LINQ data into a DataTable, and return that:

```
Imports System.Data.DataTableExtensions

' ...

' Example LINQ query comparing two DataTables. Use the query you need.
Dim q = From a In DataTable1.AsEnumerable(), b In DataTable2.AsEnumerable() _
                Where a!product_id = b!field_xyz _
                Select a!field_1, a!field_2, a!field_3

Dim results As New DataTable
results.Columns.Add("field_1")
results.Columns.Add("field_2")
results.Columns.Add("field_3")

For Each item As Object In q

    results.Rows.Add(item.field_1, item.field_1, item.field_1)

Next

Return results
```

Comment: do I need to put this code in the code of my function or in the code of my form?

edit: nvm, didn't see the return. Tx for the help btw

Comment: Does this explain why the code work in debug mode but not after publishing?

Comment: Added more info to my qustion under the codepart. I really have no idea why it gives these errors after publishing

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst To be fair, the question was totally different at the time HardCode answered.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks, I see that now - the original question was pretty vague!

Answer (score 0):

You're getting "Sequence contains no elements", which means that it's like a problem retrieving your dataset (and that there are no items in your dataset).

Inside your stack trace I can see

> bij System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
>   bij TreinplannerBL.TreinController.getStation(String station)

Which indicates that *inside* your `getStation` method, you're using `First` and it is failing because there are no elements in the collection.

Without seeing what's inside that method I can only guess, but it will look something like this:

```
Public Function getStation(string station) As Station
    ' get someCollectionOfStations from somewhere (or perhaps already retrieved), 
    ' maybe apply a select ... where on the collection 
    Return someCollectionOfStations.First()
End Function
```

This highlights two possible problems:

- there's a problem evaluation the query to get the stations and they aren't retrieved;
- there aren't any stations, in which case `First` throws an exception. What should happen in this situation?

Unfortunately the code you've posted doesn't match the exception you've posted so I can't give any further advice.

Comment: @user1054677 Given the update, the problem is that `From s In treinDataContext.Stations Select s Where s.naam = station` has no items in it. Unfortunately I can't tell you *why*... are you sure the database has items in it? Are you able to connect to the database in other parts of your program?

Comment: as parameter I give a station chosen in a combobox. The problem is when I load form I do <cbx1.selectedindex = -1>. So cbx1.text = "". So in fact, my function gets the parameter "" instead of the name of a station. That's why it gets not elements. I'll try with a try catch and see how it works out

Comment: @user1054677 Remember, you can also use `FirstOrDefault`, which returns the first match, or `null` if there are no matches.